# i want to assign the last element from chars array to the first index of arr array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

what is wrong with the for loop logic?

```
$chars = ["o", "r", "e", "z", "l", "E"];

$count = 0;
$arr = [];

foreach($chars as $values)
{
  while($values != NULL)
  {
    $count ++ ;
    break;
  }
}

for($i = $count; $i > 0; $i--)
{
  for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
  {
    $arr[$j] = $chars[$i];
  }

}

print_r($arr);
```

i want to assign the last element from chars array  to the first index of arr array .

Comment: Could you provide desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to invert the array, in your example :

```
$chars = ["o", "r", "e", "z", "l", "E"];
//Invert index
$arr = ["E", "l", "z", "e", "r", "o"];
```

you can just use [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-reverse.php) like this :

```
$arr = array_reverse($chars)
```

If you still want to create your own loop, you can do something like this :

```
  $count = count($chars);

  for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
  {
    $arr[$j] = $chars[$count - $j - 1];
  }
```